# How to prove the integral inequality $\int_{x}^{+\infty}e^{-t^2/2}\,dt\geq\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x^3}\right)e^{-x^2/2}$?

Tags: probability, integration, inequality, probability-distributions

I have to prove that for every $x>0$, 
$$\int_{x}^{+\infty}e^{-t^2/2}\,dt\geq\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x^3}\right)e^{-x^2/2}$$
holds. I thought about a probabilistic approach, but I wasn't able to prove it.

Answer (score 5):

$$\int_{x}^{+\infty}e^{\frac{x^2-t^2}{2}}\,dt = \int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-xt}e^{-t^2/2}\,dt\geq\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-xt}\left(1-\frac{t^2}{2}\right)\,dt=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x^3}.$$

The Mills ratio for the normal distribution is well-studied. Have a look at [this article](http://arxiv.org/abs/1012.2063), for instance.

Comment: (+1) It's amazing that some good answers don't get any votes. It might be that the question has very little context.